# Why a white clear image target is hard to detect (shows 0 rating) on Vuforia database

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

Well I uploaded the white image to Vuforia database and I was assuming that it will be pretty much easy for Vuforia to detect this white clear image target. But it shows 0 rating and it also unable to detect on web camera.

I already uploaded various images to Vuforia database and those images with at least 2 stars rating worked fine. But in case of white image it shows 0 rating.

So my question is **Why a white clear image target is hard to detect on Vuforia?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you uploaded a white image there is no contrast changes and gives you a zero rating

From [Vuforia developer portal](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Optimizing-Target-Detection-and-Tracking-Stability.html):

> Vuforia is able to recognize and track targets by analyzing the
>   contrast based features of the target that are visible to camera. You
>   can improve the performance of a target by improving the visibility of
>   these features through adjustments to the target's design, it's
>   rendering and scale, and how it's printed.

[image: vuforia Image Target]

[image: vuforia Image Target with targets shown]

Each cross position forms the signature of your image and every image from the AR camera will be compared to that signature

Vuforia algoritm not only checks contrast but also corners, so if you upload a black circle you will also get a very low score rating, the best images are those with high contrast and a lot of corners

[image: Low rating image]

[image: Low rating image analyzed]

In the upper example you will see a high contrast but low corner count image, thus you will get a poor score

Read Vuforia Documentation, it will help you understand how can you improve your image to achieve better results

https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Optimizing-Target-Detection-and-Tracking-Stability.html